# Javascript @media min size - only activate at a certain window size

Tags: javascript, css

I have a javascript that I only want to work when window size is a min of 1326px

This is what I did, but it is not working. The script runs regardless of what window size.

If you look at the first two lines, that is what I used to try and detect my window size.

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 1326px)" );
if (mq.matches)
    {
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("sidebar-loc").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    }
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("sidebar-loc").style.marginLeft= "0";
    }
    ( function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        slider();
    });
    } ) ( jQuery );
    ( function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    slider();
    });
    } ) ( jQuery );
    function slider() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 700)
            ( function($) {
            $('#sliderr').stop().animate({"margin-left": '0'});
            } ) ( jQuery );
        else
            ( function($) {
            $('#sliderr').stop().animate({"margin-left": '-200'});
            } ) ( jQuery );
    }
    (jQuery);
    ( function($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#show_arrow").hide(); //hide your div initially
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 700) { //scrolled past the other div?
                $("#show_arrow").show(); //reached the desired point -- show div
            }
            else($(window).scrollTop() < 700) 
                $("#show_arrow").hide();
        });
    });
    } ) ( jQuery );
    }
```

Comment: Try this `if ($(window).width() > 1326) {//do something}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener

Somewhat like this

```
if (matchMedia) {
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1326px)");
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you only check if the media query matches once when the code runs.

The solution is to wrap the whole code in `mq.addListener(function (e) { code })`. The `e` object also has property `.matches`, or you could still use the `mq.matches`, that one is also updated on change.

Also keep in mind that this feature is still a working draft and is [not supported in some older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=MediaQueryList). If you want support in those browsers, you'll have to listen for window resize event and determine if the media query matches based on window width.